Set server variable in URL Rewrite
I use Application Request Routing with URL Rewrite where I want setup Server Variable (HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_EXTENSION) in installer. There are two config for configuration

web.config which I can configure correctly using ServerManager class
applicationHost.config where I have problem

I tried using principles described in MS IIS Help.
Example of my code with dexription:
Configuration applicationHostConfig = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
// Section Path is not working. I get the string from applicationHost.config after manually 
// adding the server variable. Look at the error listing below.
ConfigurationSection section = applicationHostConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables/add", "MyWeb");
ConfigurationAttribute enabled = section.GetAttribute("name");
enabled.Value = "HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_EXTENSION";


// Part from MS example which working fine.
ConfigurationSection section = applicationHostConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/defaultDocument", "MyWeb");
ConfigurationAttribute enabled = section.GetAttribute("enabled");
enabled.Value = false;
serverManager.CommitChanges();

Error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Filename: \\?\C:\WWW\MyWeb\web.config
Error: The configuration section 'system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables/add' 
cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

I don't know why it tries to read from web.config when I use GetApplicationHostConfiguration()

You need to edit applicationHost.config by hand - or use an XDT file to transform applicationHost.config during MSDeploy - you can't do it at runtime.

Thanks for comment Dai, but XDT needs more than simple XDT file. I found another solution with appcmd.exe. From my side it is still not so clean, but I will tried it use in wix installer.
appcmd.exe set config "MeWeb" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/allowedServerVariables /+"[name='HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_EXTENSION']" /commit:apphost

You need more information to analyze your problem, can you share your configuration information?
